# Search node in xml by using Nokogiri xpath (with xml namesapce)

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri, xml-namespaces

I found Nokogiri  is quite powerful on dealing with xml but I met a special case

I am trying to search a node in xml file like this

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
     <ConfigurationSection>
      <Configuration xmlns="clr-namespace:Newproject.Framework.Server.Store.Configuration;assembly=Newproject.Framework.Server" >
       <Configuration.Store>SqlServer</Configuration.Store>
       <Configuration.Engine>Staging</Configuration.Engine>
      </Configuration>
   </ConfigurationSection>
```

When I do a

```
xml = File.new(webconfig,"r")
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml.read)
nodes = doc.search("//Configuration.Store")
xml.close
```

I got empty nodes. Something  am I missing? I have tried

```
 nodes = doc.search("//Configuration\.Store")
```

still no luck.

Updated: I have attached the whole xml file

Updated the xml  Again: My mistake, it does have a namaspace

Comment: Wild guess: is there a namespace in the XML file?

Comment: @choroba I have attached the whole xml file, looks no namespace

Comment: Works for me using Ruby 1.9 and Nokogiri 1.5.0. (Also, note that a single backslash in a string would escape the next character in the string; if you wanted a string with a literal backslash you would need `"//Configuration\\.Store"`. But this is not necessary as what you have posted works fine with no escaping.)

Comment: Works for me, too (Ruby 1.8.7).

Comment: Updated the xml  Again: My mistake, it does have a namaspace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT #2: Solution now includes `#parse_with_namespace`

You can find a number of Nokogiri methods pertaining to namespaces in the [Nokogiri::XML::Node documentation](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html).

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'rspec'
require 'nokogiri'

XML = <<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <ConfigurationSection>
   <Configuration xmlns="clr-namespace:Newproject.Framework.Server.Store.Configuration;assembly=Newproject.Framework.Server" >
    <Configuration.Store>SqlServer</Configuration.Store>
    <Configuration.Engine>Staging</Configuration.Engine>
   </Configuration>
</ConfigurationSection>
XML


class ConfigParser
  def parse(xml)
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml).remove_namespaces!
    configuration = doc.at('/ConfigurationSection/Configuration')
    store   = configuration.at("./Configuration.Store").text
    engine  = configuration.at("./Configuration.Engine").text
    {store: store, engine: engine}
  end

  def parse_with_namespace(xml)
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
    configuration = doc.at('/ConfigurationSection/xmlns:Configuration', 'xmlns' => 'clr-namespace:Newproject.Framework.Server.Store.Configuration;assembly=Newproject.Framework.Server')
    store   = configuration.at("./xmlns:Configuration.Store", 'xmlns' => 'clr-namespace:Newproject.Framework.Server.Store.Configuration;assembly=Newproject.Framework.Server').text
    engine  = configuration.at("./xmlns:Configuration.Engine", 'xmlns' => 'clr-namespace:Newproject.Framework.Server.Store.Configuration;assembly=Newproject.Framework.Server').text
    {store: store, engine: engine}
  end
end

describe ConfigParser do
  before(:each) do
    @parsed         = subject.parse XML
    @parsed_with_ns = subject.parse_with_namespace XML
  end

  it "should be able to parse the Configuration Store" do
    @parsed[:store].should eq "SqlServer"
  end

  it "should be able to parse the Configuration Engine" do
    @parsed[:engine].should eq "Staging"
  end

  it "should be able to parse the Configuration Store with namespace" do
    @parsed_with_ns[:store].should eq "SqlServer"
  end

  it "should be able to parse the Configuration Engine with namespace" do
    @parsed_with_ns[:engine].should eq "Staging"
  end
end
```

Comment: Updated the xml  Again: My mistake, it does have a namaspace

Comment: Is there a way to keep the xmlns information?  I just wantto do minor tweaks and save it back

Comment: Updated again with a new method that retains the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'nokogiri'
XML = "<Configuration>
  <Configuration.Store>SqlServer</Configuration.Store>
  <Configuration.Engine>Staging</Configuration.Engine>
</Configuration>"
p Nokogiri::VERSION, Nokogiri.XML(XML).search('//Configuration.Store')
#=> "1.5.0"
#=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x8103f0f8 name="Configuration.Store" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x81037524 "SqlServer">]>]

p RUBY_DESCRIPTION
#=> "ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0]"
```

Comment: Updated the xml  Again: My mistake, it does have a namaspace